# How to identify an initial about:blank page that was opened without navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, popup

I did some research, and understood that when a browser opens a window using window.open, it first opens a blank page with a location of "about:blank", this happens without navigation.

And then a navigation is made to the url specified in the window.open call, or the url is loaded(not sure).

**Assuming I have a script that runs before any other script or DOM was loaded(Electron preload).**

Is there any way to Identify when a window is the initial blank about:blank or not, for example, a window with location about:blank that was explicitly navigated to.

In addition:
Checking the window.location.href will not solve the problem, because I am trying to distinguish between the initial about:blank page that is opened in every window.open call before the requested URL was loaded, and a window with location of about:blank that was explicitly opened to about:blank e.g window.open('about:blank')

Comment: What are you having trouble with?
Or is it a technical interest?

Comment: My issue is related to Electron(I hope you are familiar).
I have an Electron app that uses a certain preload script.
As I mentioned in the question, preload scripts run before the page is loaded(DOM or other scripts). 
In the current situation, when a new window is opened, my preload script runs in the about:blank initial page and then again after the actual URL is loaded.
I would like to prevent the preload script from running in the initial about:blank page